# IEEE template with margin error

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

My problem is that I'm submitting an IEEE conference paper for review, but I'm getting an error as the attached snapshot.

I tried to use

```
\documentclass[conference, letterpaper, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
```

and

```
\documentclass[conference, a4paper, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
```

but it is not working, and I didn't modify or change the paper size in the rest of the document. Any idea what is the problem here.

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[conference, letterpaper,10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,snakes}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\tikzset{options/.code={\tikzset{#1}}} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta,shadows.blur,shadings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\definecolor{sky}{HTML}{C6D9F1}
\definecolor{skybox}{HTML}{5F86B3}
\def\Conf{Test}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\input{glossary}
\makeglossaries

\graphicspath{{\Conf /Figures/}}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without you providing any code to replicate this, there is not much we can do to help. We don't know what is in your document, or even your preamble. Note for example that if you have been asked to use a template, then you never change the layout or fonts of that template.

Comment: Since we don't know anything about your article we can only guess what is going wrong. Apparently on the page 5 you have something which protrude out of column. For height is impossible to say anything.

Comment: On page 5 I have only text no figures or tables

Comment: I have uploaded my preamble, as you can see I didn't change the font or the layout